# Pass parameters to --custom-data Cloud Init script using az cli

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-cli, cloud-init

Is there a way to pass parameters to the cloud init script? Trying to achieve something like this:

`az vm create ... --custom-data myscript.yml param1 param2`

Obviously it is possible to use variables from an ARM template like here: https://github.com/Azure/iotedge-vm-deploy/blob/master/cloud-init.txt#L44

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you made the mistake. It's not the parameter for the CLI command `az vm create`, it's a variable of the Azure Template. You can see the variable [`docs`](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge-vm-deploy/blob/master/edgeDeploy.json#L86) is defined in the template variables block, and of course, you can then use it in the template for the VM property [customData](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge-vm-deploy/blob/master/edgeDeploy.json#L188).

Now the CLI command `az vm create` does not support the parameters for the `--custom-data`. You can get more details about the cloud-init for Azure VM [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/using-cloud-init).