# access secret in keyvault from customData (cloud-init) section in ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, cloud-init

Is it possible to get a secret from the key vault from inside the custom data (cloud-init) portion of a parameter file in an ARM template? This is what I am trying to accomplish:

I need to inject a config.json file to a vm to a specific location, for simplicity, let's say /tmp. I am thinking about using cloud-init.

the config.json file looks like this:

```
#other cloud-init directives here....
"user": {
        "username": "admin",
        "password": "password",
        "role": "system_administrator",
        "type": "local"
    }
```

it goes without saying that I am looking for a way to not hard code the password inside the file that I will create with cloud-init. Is it possible to call a secret from inside a cloud-init configuration?

If the above is not possible, can I create a variable in my arm template (that gets the password from the key vault) and then reference that variable in the cloud-init configuration?

If that is not possible either, does anyone have a recommendation on how to possibly create a config file in cloud-init that has a password?

Any ideas are welcome, ultimately the arm template will be deployed using azure DevOps, so perhaps there is another way? or maybe cloud-init isn't the way to go?

Comment: Have you tried following the Microsoft Tutorial for access Keyvault Secrets during an ARM deployment? You can find the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-tutorial-use-key-vault)

Comment: thanks @ConnorDickson I did see that one. I was hoping to somehow get the secret into cloud-init though, but I am starting to think it's not possible.

Comment: I think this may be what I am looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60745930/pass-parameters-to-custom-data-cloud-init-script-using-az-cli   Will try and update.

Comment: This certainly works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60745930/pass-parameters-to-custom-data-cloud-init-script-using-az-cli   although it would be nice to be able to write out the cloud-init directives in the parameter file, as opposed to cramming them on a single line. If anyone knows if you can put your cloud-init config directly onto the parameters file or the template directly, let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your issue is exactly, but you can use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-tutorial-use-key-vault) article to figure out how to use the key vault secrets in the template, its pretty straight forward.

Couple of notes:

1. you will have to use concat to insert the secret into a single line you mention in your question
2. I'm reasonably sure you need to provide the cloud-init text as a single line encoded in base64, there is no way around that
3. you can also do something like this in cloud-init, which can ease your pain a bit:

```
#include
http://somesite.com/path/to/cloud-init.txt
```

Comment: Thank you @4c74356b41.  I hope at some point cloud-init directives can just be typed in a multiline parameter. If I remember correctly that's completely doable in Cloudformation templates

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend wrapping a Managed Identity to the VM that has AccessPolicy READ to the Keyvault. Then just pull the value via Powershell or API (invoke-restmethod) as an inline command in the CustomData field.